# What does this assembly l code mean?

Tags: assembly

In a program source code ,I saw the following. What does this code do exactly?

```
.CODE
FOO PROC
   nop
   nop

   push rax
   push rax
   mov rax, 545h 
   mov [rsp+8], rax
   pop rax 
   ret
FOO ENDP
END
```

then used like this for a dll export:

```
extern "C" void __stdcall FOO(void);
```

Comment: Did you look up those instructions in [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)?

Comment: thanks about reference ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It pushes two values, modifies one of them, but only pops one. That leaves one value for the `ret`.

It is unclear how this is better than `jmp 545h` though.

Comment: what is rsp+8? and why 2 time and more use nop

Comment: The nops do nothing, so they are either to align the code properly or to reserve space for later modifications. Possibly some code that is added when the dll is loaded. The address `[rsp+8]` is 8 bytes from the stack pointer, which is where the first push has ended up.